# How to concat a string in Python

Tags: python

```
query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time=%s", (mytime)
```

Currently, I"m doing this, but I want to split it into 2 strings (so I can do them separately)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time=%s",(mytime))
```

Then, I want to add a limit %s to it. How can I do that without messing up the %s in mytime?

Edit: I want to concat query2, which has "LIMIT %s, %s"

Comment: Can you also post the code you are using to execute the query?

Comment: I love SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

Being wary of SQL injection, you can dynamically compose your query [as Ignacio suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549672/how-to-concat-a-string-in-python/2549686#2549686).

```
>>> qry = 'SELECT t.mycol FROM mytable t WHERE t.mycol = %%s %s' % 'LIMIT %s,%s'
```

You ask:

> How can I do that without messing up
>   the %s in mytime?

Notice that you escape the first `%s` with an additional `%`.
That gives you this string (which of course looks lovely as far as the [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) is concerned):

```
>>> qry
'SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE t.mycol = %s LIMIT %s,%s'
```

Then pass this string and your parameters to the `execute()` method:

```
curs.execute(qry, (mytime,1,2,))
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
cxn.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time=%%s LIMIT %d" % (mylimit,), mytime)
```

Or:

```
cxn.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time=%s" + (" LIMIT %d" % (mylimit,)), mytime)
```